# AuthorizationAttribute IsAuthorized not called

Tags: c#, attributes, authorization

I've created a custom attribute that derives from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AuthorizationAttribute and overrides the IsAuthorized method.

I've decorated my methods with the new attribute but the IsAuthorized method is never called. Can anyone explain why?

Here's my attribute declaration :

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class AuthorisationAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AuthorizationAttribute
{
    private bool IsAuthorised { get; set; }

    public AuthorisationAttribute(bool isAuthorised)
    {
        IsAuthorised = isAuthorised;
    }


    protected override AuthorizationResult IsAuthorized(IPrincipal principal, AuthorizationContext authorizationContext)
    {
        return IsAuthorised ? AuthorizationResult.Allowed : new AuthorizationResult("You are not authorised for this activity");
    }
}
```

and here is my usage :

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Authorisation(true)]
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pass");
    }

    [Authorisation(false)]
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Shouldn't see this");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

With **very** few exceptions, attributes aren't injection points. They don't do anything *at all* by themself. They are **just** metadata (information about types / members). For them to be *active*, you need the calling framework to explicitly check for them (via reflection), and invoke any methods.

This is the case in some places; MVC uses attributes extensively, for example. But this is not the case for winform event-handlers and other arbitrary methods. So nothing happens.

Basically, you've done the equivalent of putting a sticky label with "do not enter" onto the door, but in a place that nobody can see by default (the top edge of the door, for example). It only does something if (both):

- somebody looks for the label
- people either electively obey the label, or you have an explicit door-person who checks the label against the people going in/out

Comment: I'd googled quite a lot before I wrote this post but it was your 'sticky label' analogy that helped me understand why my code wasn't doing what I expected it to most. Thanks Marc. Now I just need to figure out how to implement the door-person without having MVC available or using CAS.. If anyone has any code samples to hand that would be greatly appreciated...